# WPF treeview item template

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a treeview filled runtime with TreeViewItem.

All parent TreeViewItem has Tag property = null. All children TreeViewitem (without other children) has Tag property = an object.

I want to show a different layout (radio button and textblock) for treeviewitem.tag object (!= null), but i dont understand how treeview item works... i tried with hierarchical and datatemplate but fail.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton></RadioButton>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Exactly how do you "fill" the TreeView with data? Please post this code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply do if and else in the XAML. Therefore all you can access are type. So what you need to do is to create 3 different types based on the original type of `TreeViewItem` Like:

```
class RadioTreeViewItem:TreeViewItem{}
class GeneralTreeViewItem:TreeViewItem{}
```

Then you use the `DataTemplate` to declare different data templates or views for different element types like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <StackPanel DataContext={Binding}>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GeneralTreeViewItem}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RadioTreeViewItem}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Of course you will need to create your tree using these new types but ultimately your tree will be the same object as a `List<TreeViewItem>`

Comment: This code not work (visual tree can be only set once)

Comment: Would you please post the code for where you assign the items to the tree. Also I have wrapped the inner data templates in a stack panel would you do that as well

Comment: Well when do you assign it's items?

Comment: I assign items runtime. TreeView items can be add/remove during execution